Doesn't run when using localhost and Websocket data isn't displaying
When running this code and have your custom certs installed; the localhost is still enabled but not one website is working. What am I doing wrong? I have asked ChatGPT to look at the code and they made a few adjustments but it is still not working correctly.  Here is my Code:

using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using WebSocketSharp;
using WebSocketSharp.Server;

namespace WebSocketDecoder
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private WebSocketServer _webSocketServer;
        private const string ProxyServerAddress = "localhost:8443";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StartWebSocketProxy();
            EnableProxy();
        }

        private void StartWebSocketProxy()
        {
            try
            {
                _webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer(IPAddress.Any, 8443, true);
                _webSocketServer.SslConfiguration.ServerCertificate = new X509Certificate2("cert.pfx", "yourpassword");
                _webSocketServer.SslConfiguration.ClientCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

                _webSocketServer.AddWebSocketService<ProxyBehavior>("/BlueBox/websocket");
                _webSocketServer.Start();

                LogMessage("WebSocket proxy server started on wss://localhost:8443/BlueBox/websocket");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogMessage("Failed to start WebSocket proxy server: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void EnableProxy()
        {
            try
            {
                RegistryKey registry = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
                if (registry != null)
                {
                    registry.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
                    registry.SetValue("ProxyServer", ProxyServerAddress);
                    LogMessage("Proxy enabled: " + ProxyServerAddress);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogMessage("Failed to enable proxy: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void DisableProxy()
        {
            try
            {
                RegistryKey registry = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);
                if (registry != null)
                {
                    registry.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 0);
                    LogMessage("Proxy disabled.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogMessage("Failed to disable proxy: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            DisableProxy();
            _webSocketServer.Stop();
            LogMessage("WebSocket proxy server stopped.");
        }

        public TextBox DecodedOutputTextBox => txtDecodedOutput;  // Expose the TextBox via a public property

        private void LogMessage(string message)
        {
            if (txtDecodedOutput.InvokeRequired)
            {
                txtDecodedOutput.Invoke(new Action(() => LogMessage(message)));
            }
            else
            {
                txtDecodedOutput.AppendText(message + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ProxyBehavior : WebSocketBehavior
    {
        private WebSocket _client;

        protected override void OnOpen()
        {
            LogMessage("Connection opened with client.");
            try
            {
                _client = new WebSocket("wss://prod-message1.wc.kixeye.com:8443/BlueBox/websocket");
                _client.SslConfiguration.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
                _client.OnOpen += (sender, e) => LogMessage("Connected to server.");
                _client.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    LogMessage("Message received from server.");
                    if (e.IsBinary)
                    {
                        var decodedMessage = ProcessDataByHeaderType(e.RawData);
                        LogMessage($"Decoded message: {decodedMessage}");
                        Program.MainForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Program.MainForm.DecodedOutputTextBox.AppendText("Decoded message: " + decodedMessage + Environment.NewLine)));
                        Send(e.RawData); // Forward raw message to the browser
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LogMessage("Received non-binary message from server.");
                    }
                };
                _client.OnError += (sender, e) => LogMessage("Error: " + e.Message);
                _client.OnClose += (sender, e) => LogMessage("Disconnected from server.");
                _client.Connect();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogMessage("Failed to connect to server: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            LogMessage("Message received from client.");
            try
            {
                _client.Send(e.RawData); // Forward message from browser to server
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogMessage("Failed to send message to server: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnClose(CloseEventArgs e)
        {
            LogMessage("Connection closed.");
            _client.Close();
        }

        private string ProcessDataByHeaderType(byte[] buffer)
        {
            if (buffer.Length == 0)
                return "Empty data";

            byte headerType = buffer[0];
            LogMessage($"Processing data with header type {headerType}");

            switch (headerType)
            {
                case 1:
                    return DecodeType1(buffer);
                case 2:
                    return DecodeType2(buffer);
                default:
                    return "Unknown header type";
            }
        }

        private string DecodeType1(byte[] buffer)
        {
            if (buffer.Length < 3)
                return "Invalid data for Type 1";

            ushort header = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 1);
            string payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 3, buffer.Length - 3);
            return $"Type 1 - Header: {header}, Payload: {payload}";
        }

        private string DecodeType2(byte[] buffer)
        {
            if (buffer.Length < 5)
                return "Invalid data for Type 2";

            int header = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 1);
            string payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 5, buffer.Length - 5);
            return $"Type 2 - Header: {header}, Payload: {payload}";
        }

        private void LogMessage(string message)
        {
            Program.MainForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Program.MainForm.DecodedOutputTextBox.AppendText(message + Environment.NewLine)));
        }
    }
}


I have no clue as no actual errors are occuring when running in Visual Studio.
I have no clue as there are 0 errors in Visual Studio.
